# Adminlte template datetimepicker behind of modal

Tags: javascript, php, adminlte

Using below js code for display datetimepicker in bootsrtap (adminlte templ) in usual page is perfect, but when appears modal calendar appears in behind of modal

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()
  
    //Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
    $('#datemask').inputmask('yyyy-mm-dd', { 'placeholder': 'yyyy-mm-dd' })
    //Datemask2 mm/dd/yyyy
    $('#datemask2').inputmask('yyyy-mm-dd', { 'placeholder': 'yyyy-mm-dd' })
    
    $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({ 
    "showISOWeekNumbers": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": true,
    "timePicker24Hour":true,
    altField: "#modal-add",
    "locale": {
        "cancelLabel": 'Баргашт',
        "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Интихоб",
        "cancelLabel": "Бекор",
        "fromLabel": "Аз",
        "toLabel": "То",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "weekLabel": "H",
        
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Як",
            "Дш",
            "Сш",
            "Чр",
            "Па",
            "Ҷм",
            "Ша"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Январь",
            "Февраль",
            "Март",
            "Апрел",
            "Май",
            "Июнь",
            "Июл",
            "Август",
            "Сентябр",
            "Октябр",
            "Ноябр",
            "Декабр"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    "linkedCalendars": true,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
    "startDate": 1,    
    "opens": "center"
      })
    
    //Date picker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,      
      singleDatePicker: true,
      
    })
    //Timepicker
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    })

  })
```